# Only text on the website when i put the api

Tags: php

I have this API for `redtube` but when I put this in my `.php` file and show the site theres comes up this, why the site does not show the videos, its only text on the site when I preview the site. Nothing shows video.

Can someone help me or know what I am doing wrong ?

`

```
// Simple url builder function.
// You can use CURL for passing HTTP GET parameters and to call     the         RedTube API.

    function RedTubeApiCall($http_server, $params = array())
     {
      $query_string =   '?';

    if(is_array($params) && count($params)){
        foreach($params as $k=>$v){
            $query_string .= $k.'='.$v.'&';
        }
        $query_string   =   rtrim($query_string,'&');
    }

    $content    =   file_get_contents($http_server.$query_string);
    return $content;
   }


   $http        =   'http://api.redtube.com/';
   $call        =   'redtube.Categories.getCategoriesList';


    $params     =   array(
    'output'    =>  'xml',
    'data'      =>  $call
  );

  $response =   RedTubeApiCall($http , $params);

if ($response) {
    // handle the response 
}


// Simple url builder function.
// You can use CURL for passing HTTP GET parameters and to    call                     RedTube API.

   function RedTubeApiCall($http_server, $params = array())
   {
    $query_string   =   '?';

        if(is_array($params) && count($params)){
        foreach($params as $k=>$v){
            $query_string .= $k.'='.$v.'&';
        }
        $query_string   =   rtrim($query_string,'&');
    }

    $content    =   file_get_contents($http_server.$query_string);
    return $content;
}


$http       =   'http://api.redtube.com/';
$call       =   'redtube.Categories.getCategoriesList';


$params     =   array(
    'output'    =>  'xml',
    'data'      =>  $call
);

$response   =   RedTubeApiCall($http , $params);

if ($response) {
    // handle the response 
}

?>``
```

Comment: What's the actual result/output and what is the expected result? (please _don't_ post the videos, just the output of the `RedTubeApiCall` function :) )

Comment: @AlexShesterov Why no videos?! :(
Jokes aside, are they really meant to produce the videos? They might give you the source of the video, but I'd assume you need to have a player of your own to display them in. That said, I haven't had the pleasure to work with their API. Yet.

Comment: @CmdrSharp, I was just kidding, I'd expect URLs as well :)